# How can I query the Log on as user of a Windows service using the command line?

Tags: windows, command-line, services

Currently `sc query` shows service name, display name and other attributes of the services installed on my box. However it does not tell me what the **Log on as** setting is. How can I get this information using the command line?

Comment: Unless you are running SQL server or Exchange, all your services are going to be running either NetworkService, LocalService or LocalSystem.  It isn't necessary to learn the differences to them, but if you really really want to, technet would be the place to start.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`sc query` queries the *current state*; use `sc qc` to read the configuration.

```
C:\>sc qc messenger
[SC] GetServiceConfig SUCCESS

SERVICE_NAME: messenger
        TYPE               : 20  WIN32_SHARE_PROCESS
        START_TYPE         : 4   DISABLED
        ERROR_CONTROL      : 1   NORMAL
        BINARY_PATH_NAME   : C:\WINDOWS\system32\svchost.exe -k netsvcs
        LOAD_ORDER_GROUP   :
        TAG                : 0
        DISPLAY_NAME       : Messenger
        DEPENDENCIES       : LanmanWorkstation
                           : NetBIOS
                           : PlugPlay
                           : RpcSS
        SERVICE_START_NAME : LocalSystem
```

Answer (score 11):

You can use "WMIC" (WMI Command Line Interface) for this:

```
wmic service where name="Power" get StartName
```

*StartName
LocalSystem*

Here's an example for a different service:

```
wmic service where name="RpcSS" get StartName
```

*StartName
NT AUTHORITY\NetworkService*