# How to Export List of All services and user owner stated on services.msc to csv

Tags: windows, windows-10, services, csv, windows-services

I want to export a list with all services and users owners "Log on as" from services.msc

[image]

In services.msc i can export the details to csv but the results are getting messy.

I saw [THAT](https://superuser.com/questions/144960/how-do-i-extract-a-list-of-windows-services-and-their-status-to-a-text-file) and [THAT](https://superuser.com/questions/315446/how-can-i-query-the-log-on-as-user-of-a-windows-service-using-the-command-line) question but it doesn't gives the "Log on to" field with the User owner NAME. It gives only:

LocalSystem
NT AUTHORITY\LocalService
NT Authority\NetworkService

I want it to display the user NAME:
Administrator
Admin

Currently i have the following powershell script:

```
Get-WMIObject WIN32_PROCESS | `
Sort-Object -Property ws -Descending | `
Select processname,@{Name="Mem Usage(MB)";Expression={[math]::round($_.ws / 1mb)}},@{Name="ProcessID";Expression={[String]$_.ProcessID}},@{Name="UserID";Expression={$_.getowner().user}} | `
Export-CSV c:\intel\test2.csv -Append
```

Which give me this:

[image]

But again i want to export not the LIVE data (services online), i want to export the services+users stated in services.msc console

Comment: If I export the list as text (tab delimited) and just drop the file in Excel it looks ok, I mean the data is already separated in columns.

Comment: Yes, but if you check closely, you will find that the columns DATA are messy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_Service | Select-Object Name, Caption, StartMode, StartName, State | Sort-Object Name | Export-CSV result.csv
```

`StartName` is the property that has the `Log On As` information.

It is better to use `Get-CIMInstance` as `Get-WMIObject` is deprecated.

```
Get-CIMInstance -Class Win32_Service | Select-Object Name, Caption, StartMode, StartName, State | Sort-Object Name | Export-CSV result.csv
```